# how to read data from multiple sheets in a single csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I am using python and i had a csv file with data in multiple sheets.

So we can read data from csv file using python as below

Suppose the data in `data.csv` file in `sheet1` is below

```
what    |   are   |  you   | doing | however
hello   |   that  |  would |   be  | useful

csv_file = "/home/user/csv_folder/data.csv" 

for line in open(csv_file,'r'):
    print line
    ..........
    ..........
```

The output for the above will be as below

```
"what are you doing however"
"hello that would be useful"
```

but in the same `data.csv` file, i had data in another `sheet2` as below

```
This    |   will   |  be   |   second  | sheet | data
That    |   would  |  lot  |   useful  | now
```

Now what i am trying to do is to print the data which is present in another `sheets`(more than 1 sheets if present in a single csv file).

Can anyone let me now how we can print the data in all the sheets present in a single `csv` file ?

Can anyone please share a bit of python code that process more than one sheet present in a single csv file ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, csv files are single sheet. You can't have multiple sheets in a csv file like you would in an xls file.

Comment: In the .csv file, how do you know where the new sheet begins?

Comment: @tim:actually i had csv file with single sheet and we will have an option to add another sheet by clicking + button at the left down corner right? So i have created multiple sheets in a single csv file.

Comment: @Kouripm: When you go to save it as a csv it will only save a single sheet.

Comment: oh k thanks tim, can u help by treating it as a xls file then ?

Comment: Save it as an xls and all the sheets will be preserved. You can deal with the xls file using the `xlrd` library as I mentioned below.

Answer (score 3):

There is no concept of "sheets" in csv file like many of the commentators have pointed out correctly.

If you are trying to read "sheets" from an excel file, here is a good blog resource for you to figure out the syntax.

http://michalisavraam.org/2009/06/manipulating-excel-files-using-python-part-1-reading-files/

Do note that if you are indeed intending to read "sheets" from an excel file, the 3rd party package recommended by the above blog link `xlrd` needs to be separately downloaded and installed in your system.  Like this:-

```
pip install xlrd
```

before you can `import xlrd` in your python script as recommended by the blog post.