# Python CSV reading multiple Tabs

Tags: python, csv

Is there a way I can use the csv reader in python to look at multiple tabs in the workbook?

I am using the following to open the file but how could I target python between tab1 and tab2 in the workbook?

```
working_file = open('X:/test/test/test_file.csv','r')
working_file_CSV = working_file.read().splitlines()
working_file= csv.reader(working_file_CSV)
working_file .close()
```

I want to read tab1 and then append it to a list in python and then read tab2 and append it to a list  as well.

Comment: could you provide a sample of the csv file?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232604/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-sheets-in-a-single-csv-file-using-python) might help you out. Possible duplicate. There is a good reference in that answer though that shows how to do what you are asking with Excel files.

Comment: I don't think you are talking about a csv file.  They don't support tabs

Comment: How are you saving a CSV with multiple tabs?  I've never seen a CSV be able to saved that way...

Comment: you are all correct. only one tab thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking about a spreadsheet (Excel format, LibreOffice etc). When you export a spreadsheet to a CSV, it only exports the current worksheet to a CSV (Spreadsheet formats are much more complex than a simple CSV file).

So there is no way to switch worksheets - simply open your CSV with a plain text-editor to see the contents yourself.